# Change terminal font color

Tags: linux, putty

I'm using putty to connect to my Linux machine. I don't like blue color font since it is not easy to read:
[image]

How to change terminal font color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I brighten up blue directories in ls --color?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545525/how-can-i-brighten-up-blue-directories-in-ls-color).  PuTTY recognizes the Linux palette sequence.

Comment: Plese see this question on superuser.com https://superuser.com/questions/198452/how-do-i-change-the-colour-scheme-on-putty